# Where can I find a end to end proof of the multidimensional ito formula wrt a d-dimensional Brownian motion?

Tags: reference-request, stochastic-calculus, book-recommendation, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations

Where can I find a end to end proof of the multidimensional ito formula wrt a $d$-dimensional Brownian motion?

Most references skip this proof or say it can be done in a similar way as in the one-dimensional case ect.

Comment: see "Introduction to Stochastic Integration" by By Hui-Hsiung Kuo section 7.5 https://books.google.ca/books?id=hrRpqLYOsyAC&pg=PA276&lpg=PA276&dq=%22Multidimensional+It%CB%86o%E2%80%99s+formula%22&source=bl&ots=G34vu86bCZ&sig=ACfU3U03lUtJ0VcIgEcLZfZkEWVofpLghw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjw3bG8iMmCAxVtIzQIHTzpDHYQ6AF6BAgIEAM#v=onepage&q=%22Multidimensional%20It%CB%86o%E2%80%99s%20formula%22&f=false and in pg35 in http://maxim.ece.illinois.edu/teaching/spring23/SDE_book.pdf.

Answer (score 0):

some references are

- Revuz-Yor 3.3 Theorem (Ito's formula)
- Theorem 5.10 (Itô’s formula) in Le Gall's book.
- ["Introduction to Stochastic Integration"](https://books.google.ca/books?id=hrRpqLYOsyAC&pg=PA276&lpg=PA276&dq=%22Multidimensional%20It%CB%86o%E2%80%99s%20formula%22&source=bl&ots=G34vu86bCZ&sig=ACfU3U03lUtJ0VcIgEcLZfZkEWVofpLghw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjw3bG8iMmCAxVtIzQIHTzpDHYQ6AF6BAgIEAM#v=onepage&q=%22Multidimensional%20It%CB%86o%E2%80%99s%20formula%22&f=false) by By Hui-Hsiung Kuo section 7.5
- and in pg35 in [Stochastic Differential Equations: A Systems-Theoretic Approach](http://maxim.ece.illinois.edu/teaching/spring23/SDE_book.pdf.)